# Accessing elements in a list of nested vectors

Tags: r

have the following list of vectors:

```
ourTeams <- list("eric" = c("tigers"), "tate" = c("vols","titans"),"heather" = c("gators","tide"))
```

need to use a for loop to access the keys, values in the list so the output looks like this:

```
eric likes the tigers

tate likes the vols and titans

heather likes the gators and tide
```

our code can't "hard code" the number of elements in the list ... so that if I add elements to one of the

lists nested in the vectors it will still work.   I'm pretty sure they want me to use a for loop.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting homework assignment. How do you intend to solve it? Hopefully not by asking for strangers on the internet to do the work for you. Just try. If you get stuck, perhaps you can ask a focused question which shows and discusses your concrete attempt.

Comment: An idiomatic way (more-so than `for`) to do something like that in R would be to use `Map` or `purrr::imap`: they both allow you to look at both the names of the elements and the contents, and will return a list of whatever you do to them. From there, you might use `paste` to concatenate strings (look at the `sep=` and `collapse=` arguments).

Comment: I suggest you first figure out how to do this to *one set*: if `x="tate"` and `y=c("vols","titans")`, figure out how to combine those into `"tate likes the vols and titans"`. Once you have that, wrap your code within `myfunc <- function(x, y) { ... }`, and then use my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
# list example
ourTeams <- list("eric" = c("tigers"), "tate" = c("vols", "titans"), "heather" = c("gators","tide"))

# list indexing
ourTeams[1]
names(ourTeams[1])
ourTeams[[1]]

# paste0 with sep and collapse
paste0( ourTeams[[2]], sep="," ) # vector of string
paste0( ourTeams[[2]], collapse=", " ) # collapse to a single string

# sprintf (%s for string)
sprintf("my stackoverflow reputation is %s", "10")

# putting this together
for(i in 1:3) {
  print( sprintf("%s likes the %s", names(ourTeams[i]), paste0(ourTeams[[i]], collapse=" and " ) ) )
}
```